# Data range between 2 dates Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need get all the values between 2 dates ( Datapicker). The user chooose dates that he want , then will show all information , but i dunno how to do that , i try it but it doesnt work :(

**The first part is my controller**

**The second one  is my searchfunction**

In the final part i added an image about my final frontend

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\ClienteModel;

class Reportecontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {


if ($request) 
        {
        $query=trim($request->get('searchText')); 

         $fechainicial = $request->input('fec_ini_instalacion');
         $fechafin = $request->input('fec_fin_instalacion');

         $Reportes= DB::table('cliente') 
         ->select('vin')
         ->whereBetween('vin',array($fechainicial,$fechafin))
         ->get();

        return view('Vistas.Reportes.index',["Reportes"=>$Reportes,"searchText"=>$query]);
        }



        }
```

```
<!---Recordar que dicha ruta llamara a nuestro metodo index  y realizara el filtro por medio del searchtext-->

{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'Vistas/Reportes','method'=>'GET','autocomplete'=>'off','role'=>'search'))!!}
<div class="form-group">

<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
     <input type="text" name="" value="{{$searchText}}" >
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{$searchText}}">Buscar</button>

    </span>
</div>

</div>


{{Form::close()}}
```

[image: Image of reports page]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the data formatting. To fix that you can create a function and call it to convert the dates from Request:

```
private function convertDate($date)
{
    if ($date === null) {
        return null;
    }

    $dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    if ($dt) {
        return $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then, call it with the dates as parameter:

```
$fechainicial = $this->convertDate($request->input('fec_ini_instalacion'));
$fechafin = $this->convertDate($request->input('fec_fin_instalacion'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to add the field vin to your cliente model's $date variable. This converts the field to a Carbon object, which can help.

```
protected $dates = ['vin'];
```

Since this is will be a Carbon instance you should convert the dates being compared to Carbon instances as well. This can be combined with Laerte's answer above. Instead of using \DateTime::createFromFormat() you just return a new Carbon instance.

```
return new Carbon($date)
```

In the past I've had issues with Laravel and comparing dates, I've found that using the built in Carbon package and converting everything to Carbon instances to be the most helpful.